How to bind a tag addition with a key?
I started using notmuch and I often use the trash tag to have emails sent to Maildir\mail-account-i\Trash through a script. When in search mode, I have to do +trash RET on a mail (or a set of mails) to add the trash tag to this(these) mail(s).
How could I tag mails with trash by pressing the delete key instead of +trash RET (I'm using use-package)?

(use-package notmuch
  :config                                         
  (defun mda/add-trash-tag-search()               
    (interactive)                                 
    (if (member "trash" (notmuch-search-get-tags))
        (notmuch-search-tag (list "-trash"))      
      (notmuch-search-tag (list "+trash"))        
      )                                           
    )                                             
                                                  
  (defun mda/add-trash-tag-show()                 
    (interactive)                                 
    (if (member "trash" (notmuch-show-get-tags))  
        (notmuch-show-tag (list "-trash"))        
      (notmuch-show-tag (list "+trash"))          
      )                                           
    )                                             

  :bind
  (:map notmuch-search-mode-map                         
        ("<deletechar>" .  mda/add-trash-tag-search)    
        )                                               
  (:map notmuch-show-mode-map                           
        ("<deletechar>" .  mda/add-trash-tag-show)      
        )                                               
  )                                                                                          

